# Link a local dependency when it shares name with npm repo

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-link

How do we `npm link` a local dependency, when it shares a name with one of the projects in the npm repo, for example `https://registry.npmjs.org/react-financial-charts`?

For example:

```
cd ~/projects/react-financial-charts  // 1: go into the package directory
npm link                       // 2: creates global link
cd ~/projects/your-project     // 3: go into some other package directory.
npm link react-financial-charts       // 4: link-install the package
```

I notice that step 4: above will actually link to the formal repo, instead of my local project that happens to share the same name.

How can we resolve this naming conflict? I want step 4: to link to my local repo, not the package with the same name inside the npm repo.

Comment: Does `~/projects/react-financial-charts` contain a `package.json`, and if so, what is the `name` field in that file? That is what you should specify as an argument to `npm link` in Step 4.

Answer (score 0):

I `cd` into `../react_financial_charts/packages`. This `packages` folder has a number of subfolders. I went into EACH and did `npm link` in each manually. Then I went back to `your-project` and linked them all in one line:

```
npm link @react-financial-charts/series @react-financial-charts/.......
```